# remover colchetes dos valores armazenados em um dicionário

Tags: python, pandas, dicionário

Ao tentar utilizar uma planilha excel como fonte de dados para meu DOCX-TEMPLATE, o dicionário que estou gerando está armazenando os valores com colchetes, e estes e colchetes estão aparecendo no texto final que é gerado em DOCX pelo Docx-Template. 
Para simplificar, utilizei uma tabela excel que contém os seguintes dados:

```
name    birth      gender
 Felipe   07/04/1988   male
```

O meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
import pandas as pd
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

file_path = 'teste.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
data = df.to_dict(orient= 'list')

doc = DocxTemplate("modelo.docx")
context = data
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

Para simplificar, meu "modelo.docx" contém o seguinte texto:
`My name is {{ name }}, i am {{ gender }} and i  was born in {{ birth }}.`

O Resultado gerado no "generated_doc.docx" é:
`My name is ['felipe], i am ['male'] and i  was born in [Timestamp('1988-04-07 00:00:00')].`

Se eu der um `print(data)`  para verificar o meu dicionário, o resultado é `{'name': ['felipe'], 'birth': [Timestamp('1988-04-07 00:00:00')], 'gender': ['male']}` .
Se eu executar o comando `data['name'] = 'felipe'` , meu dicionário ficará : `{'name': 'felipe', 'birth': [Timestamp('1988-04-07 00:00:00')], 'gender': ['male']}`  e funcionará. Portanto, preciso descobrir uma maneira de alterar todos os valores armazenados, de modo a remover os colchetes deles. Ou senão, existiria alguma maneira de já armazena-los sem os colchetes? Eu li a documentação do read_excel() e do to_dict(), porém não consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O fato de que seu dicionário está assim: `{'name': ['felipe'], 'birth': [Timestamp('1988-04-07 00:00:00')], 'gender': ['male']}` indica que cada valor no dicionário é uma lista, com um único elemento.

Então o "remover colchetes" na verdade é criar um outro dicionário (ou atualizar o mesmo), de forma que todas as listas de um único elemento deixem de ser listas e passem a ser elementos.

Uma das formas de se criar um novo dicionário é usar uma "dict comprehension" - uma expressão com um `for` na mesma linha - o dict-comprehension economiza umas 2 ou 3 lihas de programa - então para ficar mais fácil entender, vou fazer "por extenso" primeiro - depois na forma de dict comprehension:

```py
novo = {}
for chave, valor in data.items():
    if isinstance(valor, list):
        novo[chave] = valor[0]  # (pega o primeiro elemento da lista)
    else:
        novo[chave] = valor

data = novo
```

Com  o uso de "dict comprehension" esse mesmo trecho pode ser escrito como:

```py
data = {chave: valor[0] if isinstance(valor, list) else valor for chave, valor in data.items()}
```

Comment: Obrigado jsbueno. Isso ocorreu pelo fato de eu ter usado a função `to_dict(orient= 'list')` no meu DataFrame, correto? Ela foi a única que me pareceu formatar o conteúdo da melhor forma para o Docx ler. De qualquer forma, solucionou meu problema !